# why array_search function returns the key of 0 element when it is asked to search for a not included value?

Tags: php, arrays

Ok here I have an array named `$fuitArray` including some integers or strings (in this case `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`). 
Everything works good when I try to set the `$searchTarget` to any of the elements inside the array, but when I try to search for anything else (in this case '`x`') it returns 9 (the key for the 0 in the array).
It will also work fine if I remove 0 from array and search for a not-included element!

```
<?php

$fruitArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

$searchTarget='x';
$searchResult=array_search($searchTarget,$fruitArray);


if ($searchResult===false){
    echo $searchTarget.' Not found'.'<br>';
}   else{
    echo $searchTarget.' Found @ key#: '.$searchResult.'<br>';
}
echo '<br>';
while(current($fruitArray)!==false){
    echo key($fruitArray).'. ';
    echo current($fruitArray).'<br>';
    next($fruitArray);
}

/>
```

i expected this to show

> 'x Not found'

instead of

> 'x Found @ key#: 9'

Comment: You have an array called $fruitArray which holds numeric values. Something tells me this is not your real data. I'm fine with masking data, but keep in mind it has to be close to what you have or it will not help you.

Comment: Yes you are right it's not the exact data I am looking for, I was working on an array containing numeric and string and accidentally I found this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search` function doesn't check types of variables by default. It means strings and numbers will be compared by numbers rules. 
For example, those rules might look like:

```
echo 0 == 'x' ? 'true' : 'false';
```

This example displays 'true' because it doesn't use strict comparison.
If you want to compare with the strict mode you should set `strict` parameter to true. For example:

```
$searchResult = array_search($searchTarget, $fruitArray, true);
```

You can get more information about the comparison in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score -2):

You can do : `$fruitArray=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];`
Then it will return : `x Not found`

Comment: yes it works, but i don't want to change the numeric values to strings!